# How can i fix this playbook

Tags: automation, ansible, devops

how can i use service_name in the condition, i tryed with set_fact but it doesn't work.

```
    - name: "create systemd service"
      template:
        src: "service.j2"
        dest: "/etc/systemd/system/{{ systemd_service[item].service_name | default(item) }}.service"
        set_fact: service_name= "{{ systemd_service[item].service_name }}"
      with_items: "{{ systemd_service | list }}"
      when: 
        - service_name == "oracle"
```

Comment: What kind of error were you experiencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set_fact` is the name of a module; it's not an argument to the `template` module. Fortunately, you don't need it; you can just write:

```
    - name: "create systemd service"
      template:
        src: "service.j2"
        dest: "/etc/systemd/system/{{ systemd_service[item].service_name | default(item) }}.service"
      with_items: "{{ systemd_service | list }}"
      when: 
        - systemd_service[item].service_name == "oracle"
        - env_vars.stdout.find('ORACLE=True') != -1
```